# Cannot read properties of undefined when it shouldn't be undefined in discord.js command handler

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I created a small command handler with a simple "ping" command. However, trying to access [`message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) shows up undefined. Why is this?

`./index.js`

```js
//Discord, fs, prefix, client etc. declarations

client.commands = new Collection()

const files = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js")

for (const file of files) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
  client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  const [command, ...args] = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g)
  if (client.commands.has(command) {
    client.commands.get(command).execute(message, client, args)
  }
})

client.login(/*token*/)
```

`./commands/ping.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Make me say pong",
  async execute(client, message, args) {
    message.channel.send("Pong!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `Message.channel` may be valid, `message` is not an instance of `Message`. It is actually an instance of `Client`. The order of the arguments always matter, and putting them in the wrong order can throw TypeErrors. There is 1 simple solution here

Make the arguments in the right order! You can either change the execution, or the declaration

```js
client.commands.get(command).execute(client, message, args)
```

This is really common and happens for more than sending messages to channels