# message.member.voice.channel; not working

Tags: discord.js, audio-player

Basically, i'm coding a discord bot and i'm trying to code a music bot / command. On line `14` whenever ?play is run (the command) i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined` (NOTE: i AM in a voice channel when i run this command) Im using discord js v.12.4 not sure how to check :/ I've gone over some stack overflow questions and they're all saying to update `message.member.voiceChannel` to `message.member.voice.channel`. btw i have tried `message.member.voiceChannel` it returns the same error.

code:

````
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

const queue = new Map();

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'],
    cooldown: 10,
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){


        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        if (cmd === 'play'){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
            let song = {};

            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {

                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
                }
            }

            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }             

                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);

                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting!');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(` **${song.title}** added to queue!`);
            }
        }

        else if(cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
        else if(cmd === 'stop') stop_song(message, server_queue);
    }
    
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now playing **${song.title}**`)
}

const skip_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    if(!server_queue){
        return message.channel.send(`There are no songs in queue `);
    }
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

const stop_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    server_queue.songs = [];
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}```
````

Comment: Are you trying to connect your bot to stage channel?

Comment: Also `message.member.voice.channel` was added in djs v13

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft no just trying to connect it to a vc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69631236/15781079 - did you put your arguments in the correct order?

Comment: @MrMythical thanks! my arguments wherent in the correct order, although when i run ?play (and im in a vc) i get my ur not in a vc message? would u know why?

Comment: What does logging `message.member.voice.channel` log?

Comment: @MrMythical ```VoiceChannel {
  type: 'voice',
  deleted: false,
  id: '890007832215318539',
  name: 'channel',
  rawPosition: 1,
  parentID: '890004508594286594',
  permissionOverwrites: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  bitrate: 64000,
  userLimit: 0,
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    members: GuildMemberManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    channels: GuildChannelManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],``` Had to delete the rest due to character limit

Comment: So it says "You need to be in a channel to execute this command!"?

Comment: @MrMythical sorry to confuse you, but it is simply printing out the error message when i try use the ?play (name) command :/