# Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making my Discord bot mute function and then it throws a weird error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users') at line 5

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'mute',
  description: 'Mute users',
  execute: (message, args, client) => {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (target) {

      var reason;

      if (!message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_CHANNELS', true)) return message.reply('❌ You dont have permission to use this command!');

      let MainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
      let MutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');

      if (!MutedRole) return message.channel.send('There is no muted role in this guild!');

      let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

      if (!args[1]) {
        reason = 'no reason provided';
      } else {
        reason = args[1];
      }

      memberTarget.roles.remove(MainRole.id);
      memberTarget.roles.add(MutedRole.id);

      message.channel.send(`<@${target.id}> has been muted because ${reason}`);
      return;


    } else {
      message.channel.send('Unknown user :<');
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm using Discord.js v13

Comment: What's undefined, message or message.mentions?

Comment: Probably `message.mentions` is undefined since it says `(reading 'users')` in the error. Try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `const target = message.mentions?.users?.first()`

Comment: Also, instead of doing a separate fetch for the member, why not just use `message.mentions.members.first()`? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members

Comment: Does this help? [Cannot read properties of undefined when it shouldn't be undefined in discord.js command handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631236/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-when-it-shouldnt-be-undefined-in-discord-js)